# Executar um Shell Script com duplo clique no Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-script

Tenho um programa em Shell, ele faz a instalação e configuração de alguns programas no Ubuntu, queria saber como compilo ou faço ele ser executado quando o usuário dar um duplo clique nele, ontem tinha achado um programa em C que faz isso, mas perdi o código e não consegui mais acha-lo.

Comment: Pra tornar um shell script executável utilize o chmod, exemplo: chmod +x arquivoShell.sh

Comment: sim a pergunt era como executar o shell dando duplo clique no arquivo .sh porque mesmo com +x ele nao executa

Comment: ma consegui, vou postar a resposta

Comment: Ok. Postei uma resposta de qualquer maneira.

Comment: por gentileza, corrija os erros no código, falta fechar o parêntese, e mesmo assim apresenta esta msg de rro: erro de sintaxe próximo do `token' não esperado `void'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom um meio fácil que encontrei como eu já tinha dito, foi criar um programa em C que rode o script e abra o terminal.

**Código em C: (main.c)**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main(void)
{
    system("gnome-terminal --command '/opt/shell.sh'");
}
```

E depois em compilo com:

```
gcc -o executal main.c
```

Então coloca ele na área de trabalho e o shell.sh em /opt

Answer (score 6):

No Ubuntu 15.04:

Abra o Nautilus e clique no menu Edit depois em Preferences. Na janela que abrir, clique na aba Behavior e marque uma das opções indicada pelas setas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além disso, o seu arquivo precisa estar com permissão de execução. A mesma pode ser concedida via linha de comando:

```
chmod +x arquivoShell.sh
```

ou via Nautilus. Para esse caso, clique com o botão direito em cima do arquivo desejado e selecione a opção Properties.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não funciona assim, tinha tentado desse método, ontem ia postar a resposta, mas estava logado pelo celular daí é bem ruim.

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho, estranho, pois no meu Ubuntu funciona e já fiz isso em várias versões. Deve ser algo diferente que você tá tentando fazer. De qualquer maneira, acho muito ter que fazer uma aplicação em C para executar um shell-script com duplo-clique.

Answer (score 3):

Dá para fazer criando um arquivo com a extensão .desktop. É necessário dar permissão de execução, clicando em propriedades e marcando a caixa de seleção apropriada. (ver imagem da resposta acima). Note que na opção Icon você pode especificar um arquivo de imagem valido qualquer (faça seus testes), no meu exemplo, vai aparecer o ícone de uma pasta. Deve ser codificado como UTF-8.

Descobri isso por conta, mas encontrei alguns artigos relacionados [desktop-file](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.pt_BR) e [Como criar atalhos lançadores no desktop](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Como-criar-atalhos-lancadores-no-desktop).

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=teste
Comment=Programinha para teste
TryExec=/home/helcio/Programas/exemplo
Exec=/home/helcio/Programas/exemplo
Icon=folder
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```